# Double unit price for bundle product after cart update

Tags: magento-1.9

Before update i have 1 bundle product with 1 item of 1 selected option
http://shot.qip.ru/00LU8g-4Kzjldg8L/ 
After changing qty to 2 and updating i have 2 bundle products with 2 items of 1 selected option
http://shot.qip.ru/00LU8g-5Kzjldg8M/ 
So problem is why my update doubling not only main product qty, but qty of all its options(unit price)
My update works through core magento method /checkout/cart/updatePost

Answer (score 0):

Have same problem.
Please try to change _addCatalogProduct function in file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php
to the next code

```
protected function _addCatalogProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $qty = 1)
{
    /*$newItem = false;
    $item = $this->getItemByProduct($product);
    if (!$item) {*/
        $item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');
        $item->setQuote($this);
        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
            $item->setStoreId($this->getStore()->getId());
        }
        else {
            $item->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        }
        $newItem = true;
    //}

    /**
     * We can't modify existing child items
     */
    if ($item->getId() && $product->getParentProductId()) {
        return $item;
    }

    $item->setOptions($product->getCustomOptions())
        ->setProduct($product);

    // Add only item that is not in quote already (there can be other new or already saved item
    if ($newItem) {
        $this->addItem($item);
    }

    return $item;
}
```

As for me these changes works correct.
If these change works for you too then you can rewrite this function using custom module and don't make changes for Core.

Comment: This code makes all items new for cart, so if i have item in cart and trying to add the same item i dont get qty increase but i get another same item in cart http://shot.qip.ru/00LU8g-6Kzjldg9v/  but still thanks.